# WCF operation in Client expects a different sets of argument than what is defined in server

Tags: wcf, messagecontract

I am new to WCF. I have a sample WCF server and a client consuming the service.
I have a OperationContract called getEmployer4 which accepts a EmployerRequestBO and returns a   EmployerResponseBO, both these 2 types are decorated as MessageContract

```
    public EmployerResponseBO getEmployer4(EmployerRequestBO rqst)
    {
        return new EmployerResponseBO
        { CompanyName = "Apple", CompanyAddress = "US" };
    }
```

my EmployerRequestBO looks like:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "EmployerRequest", WrapperNamespace ="http://mycompany.com/services")]
public class EmployerRequestBO
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/services")]
    public string LicenseKey
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private int _regID;
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Name = "CompanyRegistrationID", Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/services")]
    public int RegistrationID
    {
        get
        {
            return _regID;
        }
        set
        {
            _regID = value;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, when i tried to call the operaiton in client with below code:

```
        ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerClient client = new ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerClient("BasicHttpBinding_IEmployer");
        ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerRequestBO request = new ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerRequestBO("ABC123", 123);

        ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerResponseBO response= client.getEmployer4(request);
```

The getEmployer4 doesnot expect an EmployerRequestBO argument, Error looks like below

[Click to see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7XE9.png)

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'CompanyRegistrationID' of
>   'EmployerClient.GetEmployer4(string, ref int, out string)'.

Can anyone explain why it is asking for primitive types instead of a MessageContract type? Thanks!

Comment: Is the service deployed on your server using the same contract as your client code?

Comment: also, try adding a parameter-less constructor to EmployerRequestBO

Comment: Hi @lockstock I am running the service in visual studio built-in IIS in my local pc, the client is running on same pc with another instance of vs. They should use same contract. Adding a parameter-less constructor doesnot seem to resolve the issue

Comment: Why are you using message contracts? This is the reason your operation signature is different to what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took quite a bit of time before I learned that, if your Operation communicate through **`MessageContract`**, you need to create the proxy like:

```
ServiceReference_EmployerService.**IEmployer** client =
new ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerClient("BasicHttpBinding_IEmployer");
```

whereas if you Operation communicate through **DataContract**, you need to create  the proxy like:

```
ServiceReference_EmployerService.**EmployerClient** client2 = 
new ServiceReference_EmployerService.EmployerClient("BasicHttpBinding_IEmployer");
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as your solution when you are able.